# How to avoid if/elif/else when one value corresponds with another?

Tags: python

What's a concise way to express a direct correlation between (apple, banana) and (red, yellow).  Although it gets the result I need, I'm just not happy with this...

```
if value == apple:
   result = red
elif value == banana:
   result = yellow
else:
   result = None
```

Tough to search for, or even work out what to title this question, but I'm sure it's a basic exercise. Isn't it?

Comment: bam! problem solved. gotta love SO :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{apple:red, banana:yellow}.get(value)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dictionary for this:

```
mydict = {'apple': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow'}
result = mydict.get(value, None)
```

Comment: ..where `mydict` is a dictionary mapping `apple: red`, etc, etc, of course.

Comment: `.get(value, None)` isn't necessary; `None` is the default.

Comment: @minitech `True` but it's fine to be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict:

```
fruit_colors = {
    apple: red,
    banana: yellow
}

result = fruit_colors.get(value)
```